# Looping through contacts on the presentation side

Tags: audience-manager

Is it possible to loop through contacts on the presentation side (Java API)? We are using SDL Tridion 2013 with MS SQL Server 2012 SP1.

Comment: You might want to add a little more information here: what have you tried? Have you looked at the Audience Manager CD API documentation?

Answer (score 8):

Only with a [custom DAO (storage extension)](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_35CC2F9DCEA34995931E181C165FCC0F)* I'm afraid - the CD API isn't really geared towards this type of behavior.

*[requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)

Comment: I believe the reasoning behind this limitation is related to security. The contacts on the CD side fall under privacy laws and this a list of them is not available on that side. You can list them from the CM side, so you could consider using the Core Service from your web application as an alternative.